# ClientRuntimeContext to ClientContext

Tags: client-object-model

I was wondering if their is any way to convert ClientRuntimeContext into ClientContext. i am retrieving the ClientRuntime context like this

```
    public File uploadBase(Document document, Folder folder)
    {
        ClientRuntimeContext clientContext = folder.Context;
    }
```

The reason for this question is that i am building a productivity layer ontop of the Client-object-model, and trying to make it as easy to use as possible

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 6, accepted):

ClientContext is derived from ClientRuntimeContext. You can safely cast one to the other.

```
public File uploadBase(Document document, Folder folder)
{
    ClientRuntimeContext clientContext = (ClientContext)folder.Context;
}
```

Tried it out here and it worked for downloading files:

```
var fileInformation = File.OpenBinaryDirect((ClientContext)item.Context, item["FileRef"].ToString());
```